# Summation in for loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Summation{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many summands?");
        int j = scanner.nextInt();
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 2; i <= j*2;i+=2){
            sum = sum + ((i-1)/(i+1));
        }
        System.out.printf("The sum is approximately %.3f %n",sum);
    }
}
```

Attempting to sum values 1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 ... to a pre-determined summand count. The problem is that the for-loop doesn't increase the sum. Every time it says the sum is 0.000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An integer divided by an integer is an integer. Use `double`.

Comment: it is irrelevant, any positive integer I choose yields the same result. If `j=1` I should get result of `0.333`

Comment: Uh, no. It is not irrelevant. `1/3` in integer math is `0`.

Comment: You edited your initial reply in which you asked what was the value of j - my reply is targeted to your first reply. I understand the mistake now, though - much appreciated.

Comment: That was someone else, I see the confusion now though. Cheers

Comment: ah, apologies, thought the reply was yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing integer division here:

```
(i-1)/(i+1)
```

Even though it's eventually assigned to a `double`, this calculation is performed with `int`s, so the division must be an `int` also.  Each division results in `0`, so the sum is `0`.

Cast one of them as a `double` to force floating-point computation.

```
sum = sum + ( (double) (i-1) / (i+1));
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupidly simple :< Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the operands to `double`:

```
sum = sum + ((double)(i - 1) / (i + 1));
```

The expression `(i - 1) / (i + 1))` keeps resulting in zero because the variable `i` is an integer.